# Alt, Course, and Speed not displaying on the LCD display

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I wrote this code for my bike computer; however, the Alt, Course, and Speed are not displaying on the LCD display although it is on the Serial monitor. The GPS module isn't returning values either.

[image: Wirings]

```
/* BaldwinOS by John Seong
   An Open-Source Project
   Version 1.0
*/

#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <TinyGPS++.h> // Include the TinyGPS++ library
#include <Wire.h>

TinyGPSPlus tinyGPS; // Create a TinyGPSPlus object

#define ARDUINO_USD_CS 10 // uSD card CS pin (pin 10 on SparkFun GPS Logger Shield)

/////////////////////////
// Log File Defintions //
/////////////////////////
// Keep in mind, the SD library has max file name lengths of 8.3 - 8 char prefix,
// and a 3 char suffix.
// Our log files are called "gpslogXX.csv, so "gpslog99.csv" is our max file.
#define LOG_FILE_PREFIX "gpslog" // Name of the log file.
#define MAX_LOG_FILES 100 // Number of log files that can be made
#define LOG_FILE_SUFFIX "csv" // Suffix of the log file
char logFileName[13]; // Char string to store the log file name
// Data to be logged:
#define LOG_COLUMN_COUNT 8
char * log_col_names[LOG_COLUMN_COUNT] = {
  "longitude", "latitude", "altitude", "speed", "course", "date", "time", "satellites"
}; // log_col_names is printed at the top of the file.

//////////////////////
// Log Rate Control //
//////////////////////
#define LOG_RATE 5000 // Log every 5 seconds
unsigned long lastLog = 0; // Global var to keep of last time we logged

#define GPS_BAUD 9600 // GPS module baud rate. GP3906 defaults to 9600.

#define SerLCD_Address 0x72

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define ARDUINO_GPS_RX 9 // GPS TX, Arduino RX pin
#define ARDUINO_GPS_TX 8 // GPS RX, Arduino TX pin
SoftwareSerial ssGPS(ARDUINO_GPS_TX, ARDUINO_GPS_RX); // Create a SoftwareSerial

#define gpsPort ssGPS

#define SerialMonitor Serial

const int statusLED = 9;

const int blueLeftLED = 8;
const int redLeftLED = 7;

const int blueRightLED = 0;
const int redRightLED = 3;

const int leftButton = A3;
const int rightButton = 11;

const int modeButton = 12;

const int buzzer = 13;

void setup() {

  SerialMonitor.begin(9600);
  gpsPort.begin(GPS_BAUD);

  SerialMonitor.println("Setting up SD card.");
  // see if the card is present and can be initialized:
  if (!SD.begin(ARDUINO_USD_CS))
  {
    SerialMonitor.println("Error initializing SD card.");
  }
  updateFileName(); // Each time we start, create a new file, increment the number
  printHeader(); // Print a header at the top of the new file

  Wire.begin();
  Wire.setClock(400000);


  Wire.beginTransmission(SerLCD_Address);

  Wire.write('|'); // Put LCD into setting mode
  Wire.write('-'); // Send clear display command

  Wire.write('|'); // Put LCD into setting mode
  Wire.write('+'); // Send the Set RGB command
  Wire.write(0xFF); // Send the red value
  Wire.write(0x00); // Send the green value
  Wire.write(0x00); // Send the blue value

  Wire.println("Welcome to");
  Wire.print("BaldwinOS!");

  Wire.endTransmission();

  delay(2000);
}

void loop() {

  Wire.beginTransmission(SerLCD_Address);

  Wire.write('|'); // Put LCD into setting mode
  Wire.write('-'); // Send clear display command

  Wire.println("Pathfinder");
  Wire.print("Bike Computer");


  if ((lastLog + LOG_RATE) <= millis())
  { // If it's been LOG_RATE milliseconds since the last log:
    if (tinyGPS.location.isUpdated()) // If the GPS data is vaild
    {
      if (logGPSData()) // Log the GPS data
      {
        SerialMonitor.println("GPS logged."); // Print a debug message
        lastLog = millis(); // Update the lastLog variable
      }
      else // If we failed to log GPS
      { // Print an error, don't update lastLog
        SerialMonitor.println("Failed to log new GPS data.");
      }
    }
    else // If GPS data isn't valid
    {
      // Print a debug message. Maybe we don't have enough satellites yet.
      SerialMonitor.print("No GPS data. Sats: ");
      SerialMonitor.println(tinyGPS.satellites.value());
    }
  }

  printStats1();
  smartDelay(1000);
}

byte logGPSData()
{
  File logFile = SD.open(logFileName, FILE_WRITE); // Open the log file

  if (logFile)
  { // Print longitude, latitude, altitude (in feet), speed (in mph), course
    // in (degrees), date, time, and number of satellites.
    logFile.print(tinyGPS.location.lng(), 6);
    logFile.print(',');
    logFile.print(tinyGPS.location.lat(), 6);
    logFile.print(',');
    logFile.print(tinyGPS.altitude.feet(), 1);
    logFile.print(',');
    logFile.print(tinyGPS.speed.mph(), 1);
    logFile.print(',');
    logFile.print(tinyGPS.course.deg(), 1);
    logFile.print(',');
    logFile.print(tinyGPS.date.value());
    logFile.print(',');
    logFile.print(tinyGPS.time.value());
    logFile.print(',');
    logFile.print(tinyGPS.satellites.value());
    logFile.println();
    logFile.close();

    return 1; // Return success
  }

  return 0; // If we failed to open the file, return fail
}

void printHeader()
{
  File logFile = SD.open(logFileName, FILE_WRITE); // Open the log file

  if (logFile) // If the log file opened, print our column names to the file
  {
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < LOG_COLUMN_COUNT; i++)
    {
      logFile.print(log_col_names[i]);
      if (i < LOG_COLUMN_COUNT - 1) // If it's anything but the last column
        logFile.print(','); // print a comma
      else // If it's the last column
        logFile.println(); // print a new line
    }
    logFile.close(); // close the file
  }
}

// updateFileName() - Looks through the log files already present on a card,
// and creates a new file with an incremented file index.
void updateFileName()
{
  int i = 0;
  for (; i < MAX_LOG_FILES; i++)
  {
    memset(logFileName, 0, strlen(logFileName)); // Clear logFileName string
    // Set logFileName to "gpslogXX.csv":
    sprintf(logFileName, "%s%d.%s", LOG_FILE_PREFIX, i, LOG_FILE_SUFFIX);
    if (!SD.exists(logFileName)) // If a file doesn't exist
    {
      break; // Break out of this loop. We found our index
    }
    else // Otherwise:
    {
      SerialMonitor.print(logFileName);
      SerialMonitor.println(" exists"); // Print a debug statement
    }
  }
  SerialMonitor.print("File name: ");
  SerialMonitor.println(logFileName); // Debug print the file name
}

void printStats1() {
  
  Wire.beginTransmission(SerLCD_Address);

  Wire.write('|'); // Put LCD into setting mode
  Wire.write('-'); // Send clear display command

  Wire.print("Alt: "); Wire.print(tinyGPS.altitude.feet());
  Wire.print(" Course: "); Wire.println(tinyGPS.course.deg());
  Wire.print("Speed: "); Wire.println(tinyGPS.speed.mph());

  Serial.print("Alt: "); SerialMonitor.println(tinyGPS.altitude.feet());
  Serial.print("Course: "); SerialMonitor.println(tinyGPS.course.deg());
  Serial.print("Speed: "); SerialMonitor.println(tinyGPS.speed.mph());
}

static void smartDelay(unsigned long ms)
{
  unsigned long start = millis();
  do
  {
    // If data has come in from the GPS module
    while (gpsPort.available())
      tinyGPS.encode(gpsPort.read()); // Send it to the encode function
    // tinyGPS.encode(char) continues to "load" the tinGPS object with new
    // data coming in from the GPS module. As full NMEA strings begin to come in
    // the tinyGPS library will be able to start parsing them for pertinent info
  } while (millis() - start < ms);
}
```

Comment: a circuit diagram might be more useful than a photo, if you haven't got a circuit diagram then that's probably a good place to start, draw a diagram and make sure your wiring matches it

Comment: Photo is useless.  Draw a schematic but this is a code Q&A site, not a circuit design round table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a passive GPS antenna, you should test it outside (or in an open window pointing the antenna to the sky) to get the satellite fix. TinyGPS lib won't give you back any data if you don't have the fix value

Comment: I did test it outside; however, I got the same result as I stated above. Also, the 'leftBlueLED' keeps blinking for some reason :(

Comment: Hi John!

Let's dig a little bit more in this issue. Could you make a code only for print GPS data in serial monitor?

Don't worry now for the LCD or the SD card, let's isolate the issue. Once you have that code, please share us the serial output

Alan and Tom gave you a good advice: Draw an schematic first; this will be useful to discard any HW issue

Greetings